# Checking whether a certain number is prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Using the primality test on [this site](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator), I found that the concatenation of the digit reversal of the first 548 odd primes in the reverse order is a prime!. It is only a 1998-digit prime, but it took more than an hour for the site's calculator to state that it is a prime.

The calculation went super slowly. Could someone here confirm that this result is correct?.

The result I got is 7693749334931393 ... 91713111753.

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a number is prime using *Mathematica*?  If so, try `PrimeQ`.

Comment: [Here's a free (fast) way to test this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/testing_notebook.html?cell1=Reverse%2F%40Table%5BIntegerDigits%5BPrime%5Bi%5D%5D%2C%7Bi%2C2%2C549%7D%5D%2F%2FReverse%2F%2FFlatten%2F%2FFromDigits%2F%2FPrimeQ%2F%2FAbsoluteTiming). It gives `True` in under a second. It's just building off free Wolfram Cloud stuff so you can give that a check too if you need something else like this. It takes like half a second for the notebook to load, but after that you can do whatever with it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right!!

```
    Reverse /@ Table[IntegerDigits[Prime[i]], {i, 549, 2, -1}] // 
   Flatten // FromDigits // PrimeQ
```

> True
>
> 7693749334931393929332939193719311937093988318837783368335831583748333\
>   8332831283308379733973977396737673167393733373727391739073107379631963\
>   7763376317639563346373631363326371633163706339533853185317539553755374\
>   5314539353335392537253715311539943194396437643364316437543944333433143\
>   7043193398333733173316339533743334331333923332339133313370331033992317\
>   2395237523352315239223122371239023302319137813181396137613361373131213\
>   9113901398033803970376031603940314037303320391031103100399921792969236\
>   9275923592939272927192909230927982788297821682758215823482738233829182\
>   3082108279721972987277727672357294721472137292729172317211727072996239\
>   6298627862386277621762366295627562746233621262716290623952195297527552\
>   1552945234529352135212523052774237427642954274421442734232427142114299\
>   3239329832383218327732173275321532743214329332333211329032792239227822\
>   1822372296227622152234229322732212223122702230229712161235123412141273\
>   1213129212311211129902980278023802180296023602350293029202720271021102\
>   3002999179913991789197913791159194913391139131917091109198819781778137\
>   8117817681168174811381328111811081987178713871777195713571747114713371\
>   3271127190719961796139619661766136617561736172611261916131619061706110\
>   6179513851975117517651955135519451345113513251115199413941984178413841\
>   1841174195413541154174419341334192417241324190419931183137317631163172\
>   3112319131703130311031792119219821382197217721952194217321132192213221\
>   7121312110213911781118111711361135111511921132117111901130117901390119\
>   0178019601360116011501940193013301130112019101310190017991993897791797\
>   6935974914973992991911970978838818877836895875835893892872832812811890\
>   8797787377967167757157347937337727917907107196386776376166956356746346\
>   1461369167163167061069953957857751759653657557451453251259053059941947\
>   8497476436416475494434493433413412491490410479398338397337376395335394\
>   3743733133713313113703392382182772172962362752152142932332922722322112\
>   9917913911911819713717613617511519419317311317213119017013011017998389\
>   73717761695357434147313923291713111753

Comment: AAHHHH..., I LOVE YOU MAN !!!!!

Comment: I WILL REMEMBER YOUR NAME !!!  : D

Comment: Glad to help..!

Answer (score 2):

```
junk = Table[
   FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits[Prime[i]], {i, 2, 549}];
final = FromDigits[Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ junk]];
PrimeQ[final]
```

(*

False

*)

This takes $0.002238$ seconds on a Mac laptop.

Comment: Note that it is the first 548 odd primes, 3,5,7,11,13,.... and not the first 548 primes.

Comment: @ToniS:  That's why the iteration starts at $i = 2$ (and goes to $549$):  Because `Prime[2] = 3`.  And `Prime[548] = 3947` and `Prime[549] = 3967`.

Comment: Damn it !!  I hate this !

Comment: Are you sure the first digit of this prime is 769374933493... ?

Comment: Nope:  $35711317191329213731434\ldots 193919332939293139334937493$.  Over and out.  Good luck.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Your `Table` is running backwards.

Comment: @BobHanlon:  How do *you* interpret "the concatenation of the digit reversal of the first 548 odd primes"?  (Not, the digit reversal of the *concatenation* of the first 548 primes."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - there are two reversals mentioned: "concatenation of the digit **reversal** of the first 548 odd primes in the **reverse** order". The primes in the reverse order requires your table iterator to be `{i, 549, 2, -1}`